# jQuery autocomplete does not display results when typing

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am creating an autocomplete in a dynamic list. It is working but not displaying result and data show in console log.

When I start typing, the input field shows the console log, and all list show this but not view.

HTML:

```
<input type='text'
    class='btnText' 
    id="symptomSearch" 
    tabIndex='1' 
    placeholder='Type words to search from repertory' onkeydown="SearchForResult(this,'RepSearch')"
    oninput="SearchSuggestionAutocom()"/>
```

jQuery:

```
function SearchSuggestionAutocom() {
    console.log(getData(cust_list.library.search.searchSuggetionWord,["12","a"]));
    var availablesearchSuggetion = JSON.parse(getData(cust_list.library.search.searchSuggetionWord,["12", $("#symptomSearch").text()]))

    $( "#symptomSearch" ).autocomplete({
        maxLength   : 5,
        source      : availablesearchSuggetion.suggestions.split(',')
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `maxLength` property in [jQuery.autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Try this:

```
$("#symptomSearch").autocomplete({
    source: availablesearchSuggetion.suggestions.split(',').slice(0, 5)
});
```

---

Also, You have multiple spelling mistakes:

> searchSuggetionWord = searchSugge**s**tionWord

```
cust_list.library.search.searchSuggestionWord,["12","a"];
```

and:

> availablesearchSuggetion = availablesearchSugge**s**tion

```
var availablesearchSuggestion...
availablesearchSuggestion.suggestions.split(',')
```

*Note the added **s**.*

Comment: thanks but not a solution sir because  same this cust_list.library.search.searchSuggestionWord,["12","a"]  api show the data in console log .

Comment: So your console.log() works? Do you know jQuery.autocomplete is part of *jQuery UI*. Do you have that included?

Comment: I checked that the but is not the same

Comment: What is not the same?

Comment: i am try following code- source: availablesearchSuggetion.suggestions.split(',').slice(0, 5)   but not show the result

Comment: Try it without the `.slice(0,5)` and see what happens.

Comment: how to recall in first autocomplete selected then space